# Categorical Products Question

Tags: category-theory

Im currently reading about categorical products in categories. The product of topological spaces etc, the product of graphs, but my stupid question is, if a categorical product is *unique*?

Edit: Also when does there *exist* a categorical product in a category? Is there any kind of condition for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Product of two objects in category is unique *up to isomorphism*. That is, if you found two objects that satisfy the definition of product, then there exists a *unique isomorphism* between these two products that respects the product structure (remember that a product is not just an object, but also two projection morphisms). This allows one to speak about *the* product of objects (since, from category-theoretical point of view, isomorphic objects are indistinguishable). This statement can be easily proven using the defining *universal property* of products.

Note that products are not guaranteed to *exist* in a particular category (though a lot of example categories do have products, like the categories of sets, topological spaces, universal algebras of any kind, including monoids, groups, rings, etc).

Comment: Actually is there any sort of condition for a product to exist? Like a condition of some kind on the category?

Comment: @JohnSmith I haven't heard of such; all proofs of existence of products I've seen constructed the product directly.

Comment: Even better, they are unique up to a unique isomorphism.  In particular, the identity map on $A$ and $B$ induce maps between the products which are isomorphisms.  It is worthwhile proving this.

Comment: @StevenGubkin nice note, updated the answer.

Comment: No, there isn't a unique isomorphism between two objects satisfying the universal property of the product of two given objects! Take $A$ and $B$ to be sets: then any set of cardinality $|A| \times |B|$ is a product of $A$ and $B$ ; but between two such sets, there is  $(|A|\times|B|)!$ isomorphism... What is true is that between two products, there is a unique isomorphism **of cones**, that is making the obvious diagram commute (remember, a product is not just an object, it comes with projections).

Comment: @Pece  Of course.  By a unique isomorphism, I did not mean that there is only one isomorphism, but that one isomorphism can be singled out (is unique) to do the job in a way which respects the structure of being a product.

Comment: @Pece probably worth adding this to answer to prevent misunderstanding. Thanks.